# Javascript code for video scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

How can I make my background video auto scroll down after playing is finished? So the client can view whats next automatically without touching the mouse. what is the java script code?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Can you replicate the problem on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Thanks for your qiuck answer. Yeah my problem is i dont know how to move my background video on my index.html file automatically down to next section which is paragraph about me. But I want to video finish first and then scroll down to paragraph automatically.

Comment: see >> http://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc

Comment: You can use `window.scroll(x,y);` to scroll the page. If you want smooth scrolling, use jquery animate with scrolling (just google it).

Comment: Is it a youtube video or a html video element?

Comment: Check this out for determining if the video/audio is over http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_ended.asp

Comment: It is not a youtube video. The video is saved in .mp4 format in my computer. <div>
     <video autoplay id="about"><button>Click me</button>
                <source src="img/lovestory2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="img/lovestory2.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
    </div>

Comment: Ok, I will see about formulating an answer with a jsfiddle ;)

Comment: I finished my answer and posted it, please let me know if I got it incorrectly so I can improve it :)

Comment: You are the man. THanks so much. It works perfect and the way I wanted...

Answer (score 1):

I made this jsfiddle to experiment and offer you with a concrete example http://jsfiddle.net/www139/14mgca3q/. I made the variable names very detailed to provide tangible understanding of what the code is doing. For smooth scrolling, use jquery animate with scrolling (just google it).
Here is a code snippet too ;)

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var element = document.getElementById('afterContent');
  video.onended = function() {
    //the video ended
    //get the distance between the element and the top of the document.
    var scrollDistance = document.body.scrollTop;
    var elemRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    var elemOffsetViewportDistance = elemRect.top;
    var totalOffset = scrollDistance + elemOffsetViewportDistance;
    window.scrollTo(0, totalOffset);
  };
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#afterContent {
  position: relative;
  top: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" tabindex="0" autobuffer="autobuffer" controls preload="preload">
  <source type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;" src="http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.webm"></source>
  <source type="video/ogg; codecs=&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;" src="http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.ogv"></source>
  <source type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/video/basics/Chrome_ImF.mp4"></source>
  <p>Sorry, your browser does not support the &lt;video&gt; element.</p>
</video>
<div id="afterContent">
  This is the div with the content.
</div>
```

I borrowed the cool video from @codelove (very cool video by the way).